# Kibana dashboard shows empty visualizations, but visualization itself works

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

This is the visualization when viewing it alone:
[image]

However, this is the visualization on the Dashboard page:
[image]

This issue seems to "randomly" affect certain visualizations in the dashboard, even though they are all the same type and use similar filters.

Comment: This is after you added the visualization you created within the dashboard?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We think it might be related to the y-axis scale, but it's really unclear.

Comment: Restarting elasticsearch process fixed things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the time range in the time picker in the top navbar

Comment: This is always the first thing I check.